# Comparing date values

Tags: android, date

I am using two functions to compare date values where I will be checking to see if **start date** is greater than/comes after the **end date**.

The 1st function is used to take in string value and use that string value to initialize the `Calendar`:

```
private int getFromCalendar(String strDate,int field)
    {
        int result = -1;
        try
        {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");// this is your date format "12/24/2013" = "MM/dd/yyy"
            java.util.Date date = formatter.parse(strDate);//convert to date
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();// get calendar instance
            cal.setTime(date);//set the calendar date to your date
            result = cal.get(field); // get the required field  
            return result;//return the result.
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The 2nd function is used to compare the startDate and endDate (they are both buttons):

```
public void compareDates(String startDate, String endDate){
            Calendar startCheckDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            int startmm = getFromCalendar(monitoringDate.getText().toString(), Calendar.MONTH);
            int startyy = getFromCalendar(monitoringDate.getText().toString(), Calendar.YEAR);
            int startdd = getFromCalendar(monitoringDate.getText().toString(), Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            startCheckDate.set(startyy, startmm, startdd);
            Calendar endCheckDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            int endmm = getFromCalendar(monitoringEndDate.getText().toString(), Calendar.MONTH);
            int endyy = getFromCalendar(monitoringEndDate.getText().toString(), Calendar.YEAR);
            int enddd = getFromCalendar(monitoringEndDate.getText().toString(), Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
            endCheckDate.set(endyy, endmm, enddd);

            if(endCheckDate.after(startCheckDate)){
                Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "End date cannot be smaller than start date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

For some reason the `compareDates` function does not work at all. Help please

Answer (score 3):

You can easily compare date by changing it to milliseconds since 1900

```
Date date = new Date();
long dateLong = date.getTime();
```

Now its easy to compare with any other date

So for your case after doing this get back in date DataType

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");// this is your date format "12/24/2013" = "MM/dd/yyy"
java.util.Date date = formatter.parse(strDate);
```

do something like

```
long date1long = date1.getTime();

long date2long = date2.getTime();


if(date2long > date1long)
{
   // Do whatever you want
}
```

#### This is the easiest way to compare two dates

Answer (score 1):

You are way to verbose. Since you only wanted to know if a given date is after another, or not. Here you go:

```
public class DateTest {
    private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MM/dd/yyyy");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Calendar start = createFromString("01/30/2013");
        Calendar end = createFromString("06/30/2013");

        System.out.println("START: " + start.getTime());
        System.out.println("END  : " + end.getTime());
        System.out.println("IS B4: " + isBefore(start, end));
    }

    public static Calendar createFromString(String date) throws ParseException {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(formatter.parse(date));
        return c;
    }

    public static boolean isBefore(Calendar start, Calendar end) {
        return start.before(end);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> START: Wed Jan 30 00:00:00 CET 2013
>    END   : Sun Jun 30 00:00:00 CEST 2013
>    IS B4  : true

I usesd `getTime()` in the `println()` method since, the `toString()` method (that gets implicitly called) on `java.util.Date` is more human readable than the one in `Calendar`.

There is also an `after()` in Calendar and a `compareTo()`.

Comment: Np. You're welcome. If the answer was what you wanted. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in the compareDates() use

`if(endCheckDate.compareTo(startCheckDate)<0)`

instead of

`if(endCheckDate.after(startCheckDate))`

for more reference [go here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/)